# Getting a Connection to a Postgresql database from a Datasource created with Spring's DataSourceBuilder

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, maven, spring-boot

I am new to Spring and Spring Boot. I am trying to connect to a Postgresql database in my Spring Boot app.
I've tried to take inspiration from

http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

and

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html

Basically I have an `application.properties` file that contains:

```
app.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_example
app.datasource.username=myusername
app.datasource.password=mypassword
app.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Using the `psql` tool I can normally connect to the `db_example` database on localhost with the 5432 port and those username and password.

Then I have a `MyConfig.java` which contains:

```
package hello;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dsb = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        if (dsb == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return dsb.build();
    }

}
```

Then in `MainController.java` one of the methods that has a `@GetMapping` annotation, I call the `dataSource()` method. On the returned object I call `getConnection()` but that throws an `SQLException` with message `The url cannot be null`.

Also in the console the Spring Boot app writes several things:

```
Not loading a JDBC driver as driverClassName property is null.
```

and

```
Unable to create initial connections of pool
```

What am I missing? I guess some annotation in `MyConfig.java`?

EDIT: You might also want to see my `pom.xml` used to package the thing with `mvn`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-mysql-data</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->

        <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I guess `driver-class-name` should be `driverClassName` in your application.properties

Comment: That doesn't seem to help...

Answer (score 3):

It seems DataSourceBuilder is not set the properties. Can you try to use the default config in Spring like:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_example
spring.datasource.username=myusername
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

More detail in here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Then in your code, you have to get these properties and set them:

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String url;
@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
private String username;
@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
private String password;
@Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
private String driver;

DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(driver);
dataSourceBuilder.username(username);
dataSourceBuilder.password(password);
dataSourceBuilder.url(url)
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Kenny, I'll try this and let know if it helped.